# module-bluez5-discover vs module-blueooth-discover?

Tags: pulseaudio, bluetooth

What's the difference between these two modules

```
name: <module-bluetooth-discover>
argument: <>
used: -1
load once: yes
properties:
        module.author = "João Paulo Rechi Vita"
        module.description = "Detect available Bluetooth daemon and load the corresponding discovery module"
        module.version = "13.0"
```

And,

```
name: <module-bluez5-discover>
argument: <>
used: -1
load once: yes
properties:
        module.author = "João Paulo Rechi Vita"
        module.description = "Detect available BlueZ 5 Bluetooth audio devices and load BlueZ 5 Bluetooth audio drivers"
        module.version = "13.0"
```

Comment: one of those hard to resolve curiosities....